# WebElement.click() click on buttons but doesn't return in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a weird problem automating IE using Selenium (java). Using the method "click" of the WebElement, the button is clicked - the the function doesn't return. I can't continue debugging my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well known problem with IE.
try to click other element - maybe the parent.
or you can use click with JS, Actions or most common in sendKeys("\n")

Comment: I will try now a few of the solutions you mentioned and update if any of them works.

Comment: Thanks, it is working for me. I used the last option you mentioned, sendKeys("\n").